How to cut steel without damaging the coating?
I ordered Miata stainless steel rails for deck and need to cut. I used a chop saw and it burnt the coating and made it bubble and look terrible. How do I cut this where it still looks good?

What sort of blade did you use on the chop saw? There exist "cold cut" blades which run substantially cooler than an abrasive blade but perhaps still make too much friction/heat. In industry liquid-cooled band saws are a common choice.

@GregHill  Have seen some ads for them, but it seem that they required a saw that looked like a normal chop saw but was three or four times more expensive.

@crip659 I bought one of the 7-1/4" size tungsten carbide tipped cold cut blades. There is a special saw for those too but I put it on my ordinary worm-drive circular saw and have had good results. Be sure to check the saw speed; some saws run much faster than the max rated speed of the TCT blades and should not be used.

Hacksaw.
Powder coating is essentially a layer of plastic. Power tools cause heating, which melts plastics.
Low speed cutting, such as hacksaw is a good bet. Even with a hacksaw you can overheat the material if you're aggressive.

If you want to cut steel with a hacksaw you need a well sharpened high quality hack saw and a good deal of patience. It can be done with a quality tool but it is a lot of work.

Yep. Stainless steel is hard and work hardening, but it's the best way to avoid heating.

Adding to @quarague : Look for a "high tension" hack saw which uses a cam/lever instead of a screw for tensioning the blade -- the cutting performance of the high-tension saws is far better.

A carbide/tungsten hack-saw works best.

The user of /any/ type of power saw should also be prepared to use a hand saw when necessary, since otherwise he will persist in using the wrong type of tool when the results show that it's inappropriate. However in this particular case it's also important to consider workholding: the workpiece will be marred if it slips in the vice, and crushed if the vice is overtightened.

You can still use a chop saw but you have to take short cuts and keep the metal cool. Water or cutting oil squirted onto the metal while cutting will reduce the heat considerably.

Might be a good idea to first score a line with a knife, for a cleaner cut.

Wrap the rails tightly with very wet cloth before cutting. Cut right through the wrap. Pause and reapply water if there's a lot of steam. This is only for abrasive blades, don't use with any saw with teeth.
It's a "poor man's version" of industrial water or oil cooled cutters, sometimes used to preserve the paint on parts being cut.

I'd be worried about cloth wrapping the blade of the saw with this method.

This is for abrasive blades only.

A jigsaw is for many purposes a powered version of a hacksaw. Plus you can operate it one-handed, which means you can direct a trickle of water or cutting lubricant  onto the blade while cutting to keep everything cool.  You want one with a speed limiter, and set it slow. Also an appropriate metal cutting blade. Go gently. Don't forget that it cuts on "pull" so your painted surface is on the bottom while cutting.
(The drawback over a hacksaw is that you won't get such a straight-line cut).
